# Tool to shows server workload status (ASP.NET + MS SQL)

Tags: iis, performance-monitoring

I want to provide our testers with tool to see live server load, like memory usage, processor usage, database etc via webpage.

There are a lot of tools which are installed on server for admin, But definitely I do not want to provide access to live remote desktop.

I am using Windows 2003, IIS, MS SQL Server, ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

SCOM (System Center Operations Manager), htough not really LIVE (live does not scale= - point.

Otherwise the normal performancecounters work - you can connect to them from a remote computer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. When I type server name in Connect to another computer dialog, I am having error "computer \\www.domain.com cannot be managed. the network path was not found". Is it firewall? I do not like how it says \\www.domain.com